# .cs files disappeared from my project folder

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008

Hai guys,
         I ve formatted my system recently and installed visual studio 2008... I have a backup of my project folder... And now when i loaded the project folder i was shocked to see all my aspx.cs files were missing... I dont know what to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest and quickest way to get your stuff back is to use [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) and just copy-paste the reflected code and adjust it back to what you had.

The code could be a bit optimized, but you should have something close to the original and a good start.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you backed up the source and not just the published project?

when you publish, cs files obviously get compiled into the DLL.

Is this a website or web app project?